# Make 18.04 and bionic synonym

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

When I add tags to the question and type [xenial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xenial), it suggests me to add [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04) but when I type bionic, no suggestion is given.

Comment: No bionic tag exists, so this can't be done right now. AFAIK the only way tags are created is when they are put on a new question by a 1.5k user, so it will have to wait until someone ask a relevant question with the tag. Until then, just type 18.04

Comment: @MarkKirby I think 300 rep is enough for creating new tags: https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: A mod can create a synonym far quicker than any of us can

Comment: @muru ... and it seems **only** mods can create synonym for version tags.

Comment: @pomsky your right, don't know where I pulled that number from :/